# C# the result of float to byte is weird

Tags: c#

```
float myfloat = 0.7f;

byte test = (byte)(myfloat * 10);
```

The result of test is 6. That is really weird. Could someone explain what happen here?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NzZSQi

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IXprh6 The second duplicate explains why your dotnetfiddle and mine give different results. The first duplicate explains why floating point maths _generally_ isn't always doing what you expect.

Comment: Note also that the results are not _necessarily_ consistent across OS and / or .NET Framework / Core versions. Hence why https://dotnetfiddle.net/4IbutH gives different results even though the code is the same.

Comment: always best to be explicit how you want to treat a float to int conversion....```byte test = (byte)(Math.Round(myfloat * 10));```

Comment: Also, for less surprises, use decimal.... but understand the differences between what numbers float/doubles represent and what decimals represent

Comment: because i want to send float data to Com Port. so I multiply them by 10.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't expect 0.7 * 10 to equal 7.